# PayPal AdaptivePayment : What happens if the secondary receiver's out of cash when processing a Refund API

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

When processing the Refund API to the payment made by AdaptivePayment Pay operation if the secondary receiver does not have enough money in their account
what happens to the API call? would it fail as whole or would the missing fees be draw out of primary receiver's account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing this scenario with instant chained payment, and refund was cancelled. So obviously its all or none.